# Who proved the snake lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, homological-algebra

The title speaks for itself; however, I would also like to know who proved that if you have a short exact sequence of chain complexes this induces a long exact sequence in homology.

It's not really of any consequence; it just might be interesting to know who first posited these ideas.

Comment: kinda relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106943/who-named-it-the-snake-lemma